# Newyork BBL to Latitude/Longitude API

Tags: python, pandas, api, csv, latitude-longitude

I want to convert NewYork BBL numbers to Latitude Longitude values. The BBL values are present as CSV file. Is there a Free API to convert them using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[These has one month free.](https://locatenyc.io/detail-bbl). If you go an sign up for a free account, this code works (I tried it out).

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

TOKEN = 'YOUR TOKEN'

def get_coord(bbl):
    url = f'https://locatenyc.io/arcgis/rest/services/locateNYC/v1/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?singleLine={bbl}&token={TOKEN}'
    resp = requests.get(url)
    data = resp.json()
    attrs = data['candidates'][0]['attributes']
    return attrs['longitudeInternalLabel'], attrs['latitudeInternalLabel']

df['coords'] = df['bbl'].apply(get_coord)
```